# iOS Safari Restrict Image Upload

Tags: ios, forms, safari

I know apple provide some attribues to use in HTML to make your web app work better with Safari on iOS. I was wondering now iOS 6 supports media uploading with the file inputs, at the moment if you select it you get two options:

```
"Take Photo or Video"
"Choose Existing"
```

I was wondering if I can set the browser to only show "Take Photo or Video"? I know I've seen some fancy Safari options before I was wondering if Apple gives you this much control? Let me know if you guys have seen anything on this. I would love to remove choose existing just because of the functionality I'd like to provide.

Comment: Are you asking how to do this through an app or through your website's code?

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to do this with website code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disable video so that the choice is only between:

```
"Take Photo"
"Choose Existing"
```

by adding /* to the accept attribute in your html:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
```

Customizations are therefore possible, in the browser at least. I'll update if I find more.

Comment: I'd given up but this partially fixes my issue! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to do this from your app, the answer is it's not possible. Apps are kept in their own sandbox and can't interfere with the operation of other apps.

I would also assume that this is not possible from code in a website either. To Safari the website wants an image. I don't believe there is any way to specify where it gets that image.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I just wondered just like you can add special mobile safari options if this was possible :) thanks!